# I am importing data from csv file and trying to show as an image in python, but the image is not displaying correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a csv file with 480x640 intensity values represented as floats.  It's just one long column.

In python I wanted to import that data and try to display it as an image. Here's the best version I've come up with so far:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
##import matplotlib
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#visual one
#df = pd.read_csv('93834016616704_DATA.csv', header=None) # read the training data file from working directory
#meter one93840538154878_DATA
df = pd.read_csv('235317464765230_DATA.csv', header=None) # read the training data file from working directory

i = 3 # set any valid index of an image
##label = df.values[i][0] # retrieve label from first colum in dataframe
#im_buf = df.values[i][1:] # create flat array of only the pixels of the given image
#axis_len = int(math.sqrt(im_buf.shape[0])) # calculate the dimensions of the square image

print("df size" + str(df.size.item()));

im_array = np.int8(np.reshape(df.values, (480, 640))) # create a 2D array from flat array
im_array = im_array.transpose()
img = Image.fromarray(im_array, 'L') # convert to a PIL.Image object ('L' is for grayscale)

#print(f'Label: {label}')
imshow(np.asarray(img))
plt.show()
```

The result is the image is rotated by 90 degrees and also chopped and copied 4 times.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you tried creating the array from the CSV using NumPy?

Comment: Why do you convert the array to an image (`fromarray`) and then in the next line convert it back to an array (`asarray`)?